# Rows getting locked while updating the table using Task scheduler in Java

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I've written a Task scheduler in Java where it calls the method for every one min. Now this application is deployed into SIT server which has 2 instances running on it. Now let me tell you the scenario which I have built.

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="myBean" method="takeLunch" fixed-delay="60000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduler id="myScheduler"/>
```

The flow is

1. Get the employees who are ready to take the lunch. This is the eligiblity condition.

   ```
   SELECT EMP_ID FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE WORK_STATUS='COMPLETED'
   ```

   (Can there be a deadlock here because both instances try to fire the query at the same time?)
2. I've another table called "LUNCH_STATUS" where I will keep track of their lunch.

   ```
   INSERT INTO LUNCH_STATUS(EMP_ID,STATUS) .....
   ```

   Here all employee ids will be inserted with the status as empty.
3. I will get the first employee from the LUNCH_STATUS whose status is empty and I will update in the same table as the status "LUNCH IN PROGRESS"
4. While taking lunch, I've some business logic, once the lunch is done, I will update the status as "COMPLETED"

   ```
   UPDATE LUNCH_STATUS SET STATUS='COMPLETED' WHERE EMP_ID  = ?
   ```
5. Once this update is done, I should update the main table EMPLOYEES

   ```
   UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET WORK_STATUS='WORK RESUMED' WHERE EMP_ID=?
   ```

   This is working fine when I run in my local machine, but not sometimes in  the SIT server.

Now, the problem here is sometimes when multiple employees are eligible for taking their lunch, the application is not updating status as Lunch completed even though the process is done. Somewhere the record is getting locked. Any ideas what steps should I have considered?

I'm using the @Transactional annotation and the isolation property as SERIALIZABLE for all these DAO methods (INSERT, SELECT & UPDATE).

Answer (score -1):

You have to implement a cluster environment quartz scheduler. for example in GitHub with the database.

Click here https://github.com/faizakram/Application

Comment: We are not using Quartz scheduler. Only option it is task scheduler for now